# Cant see greek menu text and titles the paragraph greek text is alright

Tags: html, css

I have my website in english and now I want to make it in greek, but the greek text it wont show in the menu bar and titles but some symbols... though the paragraph greek text looks just fine.
I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: What editor do you use?I had the same problem because my editor did not save the text as utf-8 charset.Check it out.

Comment: Front page and dreamwaver

Answer (score 1):

The `HTML lang attribute` can be used to declare the language of a Web page. This is meant to assist search engines and browsers.

According to the W3C recommendation you should declare the primary language for each Web page with the lang attribute inside the  tag, like this:

`ISO 639-1` Language Code of greek is `el`

```
<html lang="el"> 
...
</html>
```

In XHTML, the language is declared inside the  tag as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="el" xml:lang="el">
...
</html>
```

Some Greek characters are part of the Unicode character set, so you need to declare that in the head of your documents:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

you may check for special characters though this [website](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-gr.htm)

Comment: thank you for the answer, I change it and is still the same, any other ideas? It is weird because the body goes in greek text very good, but only the titles and the menu bar is with some symbols.

Comment: @Clau, why did you accept the answer if it did not solve the problem?

Comment: There is no reason to think that the `lang` attribute addresses the problem in any way.

Comment: yeah by mistake... there is any other solution I should try?